# React Native - Appearance keeps throwing 'Invalid hook call' error

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, appearance

I'm trying to use the Appearance (useColorScheme) hook in order to get the theme of the device (dark or light).

I **do** use hook and my component is a function (see my code below). The problem is that I keep getting this error :

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and  the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I obviously checked the reasons why this would throw an error and I follow by the book the examples of official documentations :

- [NPM documentation of appearance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-appearance)
- [EXPO documentation of
  appearance](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/appearance/)

I keep getting this error, even though the root of my app is well surrendered by Appearance like so :

```
  <AppearanceProvider>
    <App />
  </AppearanceProvider>
```

Here is my working code, if I uncomment the 2 first lines I get the error above.

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you :

```js
import { AppearanceProvider, useColorScheme } from 'react-native-appearance';

export default function Colors(props)
{
  let themeIndex = 0;
  //themeIndex = useColorScheme() === "dark" ? 1 : 2; <------- Throws an error
  //console.log("theme = " + useColorScheme()); <------- Throws an error too

  const themes = [
    { Name: "Light", Background: "f1f1f1", Foreground: "ffffff" },
    { Name: "Dark", Background: "222222", Foreground: "333333" },
  ];

  return {
    Background:("#" + themes[themeIndex].Background),
    Foreground:("#" + themes[themeIndex].Foreground),
  };
}
```

Comment: SOLUTION : I continued the research and ended up using 'Appearance.getColorScheme()' which works in any case. The only downside is that I need to add a listener on the value change, but at least I wasn't getting the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`useColorScheme` is a hook you can't access that in your `function Colors` since it is a **non-react** component.

You can use parent `props` to get value.

```
export default function Colors(props) {
  let { themeIndex = 0 } = props;

  const themes = [
    { Name: 'Light', Background: 'f1f1f1', Foreground: 'ffffff' },
    { Name: 'Dark', Background: '222222', Foreground: '333333' },
  ];

  return {
    Background: '#' + themes[themeIndex].Background,
    Foreground: '#' + themes[themeIndex].Foreground,
  };
}
```

Parent.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { AppearanceProvider, useColorScheme } from 'react-native-appearance';

import Colors from './Colors';

export default function App() {
  console.log('test');
  const themeIndex = useColorScheme() === "dark" ? 1 : 0;
  const theme = Colors({ themeIndex })

  return (
    //...
  );
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please share the code where you are using this `Colors()`.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer, no luck with this either, I kept having the exact same error. Good news though, I continued the research and ended up using 'Appearance.getColorScheme()' which works in any case. The only downside is that I need to add a listener on the value change, but at least I wasn't getting the error. Are you sure what you're saying is true ? Because if I follow the example on the official doc, we can clearly see : "function MyComponent() { let colorScheme = useColorScheme();..." here : https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/appearance/